# Setting up Apache POI API in Netbeans,

Tags: java, apache-poi

What are the steps for setting up Netbeans for Apache POI API? Which files must I download from http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.9

Answer (score 1):

That depends on which formats you want to process.

Just look at the [POI components docs](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)!